# Can't find all classes in Android

Tags: java, android

I try to get all classes' names using **DexFile**:

```
private List<String> getAllClasses() throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> classes= new ArrayList<String>();
        DexFile df = new DexFile(getPackageCodePath());

        for (Enumeration<String> iter = df.entries(); iter.hasMoreElements();) {
            String s = iter.nextElement();
            classes.add(s);
        }
        return classes;
    }
```

After disabling of **Instant Run** I find more classes ( size = 4157). I can even get classes from external library. But that is not all. I still can't find classes from java.lang, android.widget (only android.support) packages and so on.

Answer (score 0):

That is because those classes are not in your app. They are part of the framework, and therefore they are not in one of your DEX files.

Comment: Can I get them with other ways?

Comment: @AKS: I do not know of a way to do that.